# does not show error message on view data in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, view, controller, viewbag

This is my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePortfolioCategory(CreatePortfolioCategoryViewModel createPortfolioCategoryViewModel)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(createPortfolioCategoryViewModel);
        }

        var result = await _siteService.CreatePortfolioCategory(createPortfolioCategoryViewModel);
            switch (result)
            {
                case CreatePortfolioCategoryResult.NotFound:
                    ViewBag.ErrorText = "Error";
                    return View(createPortfolioCategoryViewModel);

                case CreatePortfolioCategoryResult.Created:
                    ViewBag.SuccessText = "Successful Create";
                    break;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

it create successful in database and redirect to index but it does not show this error and successful message on index

I write this code on view but this message on viewbage doesn't show on view. it show just " Successful"

```
  <div>
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.ErrorText))
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <p>@ViewBag.ErrorText</p>
    </div>
}

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.SuccessText))
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p>@ViewBag.SuccessText</p>
    </div>
}
```

```
  <h2> Successfull </h2>
```

This is the create method on service:

```
        public async Task<CreatePortfolioCategoryResult> CreatePortfolioCategory(CreatePortfolioCategoryViewModel createPortfolioCategoryViewModel)
    {
        if (createPortfolioCategoryViewModel.ParentId != null && !await _portfolioRepository.IsExistPortfolioCategory(createPortfolioCategoryViewModel.ParentId.Value))
            return  CreatePortfolioCategoryResult.NotFound;

        PortfolioCategory portfolioCategory = new PortfolioCategory()
        {
            PortfolioTitle = createPortfolioCategoryViewModel.PortfolioTitle,
            NameInUrl = createPortfolioCategoryViewModel.NameInUrl,
            IsDelete = createPortfolioCategoryViewModel.IsDelete,
            IsActive = createPortfolioCategoryViewModel.IsActive,
            Order = createPortfolioCategoryViewModel.Order,
            ParentId = createPortfolioCategoryViewModel.ParentId
        };

        await _portfolioRepository.CreatePortfolioCategory(portfolioCategory);
        await _portfolioRepository.SaveChange();
        return CreatePortfolioCategoryResult.Created;

    }
```

Comment: Please provide your `_siteService.CreatePortfolioCategory()` method and `CreatePortfolioCategoryResult`. Have you tried adding breakpoints to step through to see if the `result` matches your judgment?

Comment: I update the question, yes I have service method and it adds to data base but does not show just message after add that I write the code in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not pass the value of `ViewBag.SuccessText` to the `Index` method, so `ViewBag.SuccessText` is always a null value in the view of `Index`.

When `SiteService` returns `CreatePortfolioCategoryResult.NotFound`, the view you return is `CreatePortfolioCategory.cshtml`, and when `SiteService` returns `CreatePortfolioCategoryResult.Created`, the view you return is `Index.cshtml`. So you can only judge whether the `SuccessText` is empty in `Index.cshtml`, and then judge whether `ErrorText` is empty in `CreatePortfolioCategory.cshtml`.

You can refer to my test code below:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(string? successText)
{ 
    ViewBag.SuccessText = successText;
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreatePortfolioCategory()
{ 
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePortfolioCategory(CreatePortfolioCategoryViewModel createPortfolioCategoryViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(createPortfolioCategoryViewModel);
    }

    var result = _siteService.CreatePortfolioCategory(createPortfolioCategoryViewModel);
    switch (result)
    {
        case CreatePortfolioCategoryResult.NotFound:
            ViewBag.ErrorText = "Error";
            return View(createPortfolioCategoryViewModel);

        case CreatePortfolioCategoryResult.Created:
            ViewBag.SuccessText = "Successful Create";
            break;
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { successText = ViewBag.SuccessText });
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<div>
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.SuccessText))
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>@ViewBag.SuccessText</p>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

CreatePortfolioCategory.cshtml:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.ErrorText))
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <p>@ViewBag.ErrorText</p>
    </div>
}
<form method="post" asp-action="CreatePortfolioCategory" >
    <div>ParentId</div>
    <div><input type="number" asp-for="@Model.ParentId" /></div>
    <div>PortfolioTitle</div>
    <div><input type="text" asp-for="@Model.PortfolioTitle" /></div>
    <div>NameInUrl</div>
    <div><input type="text" asp-for="@Model.NameInUrl" /></div>
    <div>IsDelete</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.IsDelete" /></div>
    <div>IsActive</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.IsActive" /></div>
    <div>Order</div>
    <div><input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Order" /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
```

Test Result:

When `CreatePortfolioCategoryResult.NotFound` is returned:
[image]

When `CreatePortfolioCategoryResult.Created` is returned:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Hasti Asadi, did my answer help you?

Comment: yes yes . it works :0 thanks so much , I have some issue for  entrance data and return them, how ever I had to show the list of my created category , now it work , I will change index page later , if I have issue I write it here again